# Чтение определенных строк из файла txt

Tags: c#, .net

Как прочитать текстовый файл с определенной строчки по определённую строчку и записать в строку, разделённую запятыми?

Answer (score 4):

Получение нужных строчек (5 строчек, начиная с 4-й):

```
IEnumerable<string> strings = File.ReadLines("../../Program.cs").Skip(4).Take(5);
```

Не понял, что такое "разделённый запятыми массив", но если нужна разделённая запятыми строчка, то так:

```
string joinedString = string.Join(", ", strings);
```

Если собственно массив, то просто `ToArray` (или лучше `ToList`):

```
string[] stringsArray = strings.ToArray();
```