# Как в C# сделать выборочное редактирование тхт UTF8 файла без полного считывания?

Tags: c#

Нужно в ТХТ файле заменить с 15 по 20 символы на другие. Как это сделать без считывания всего файла. Формат UTF8 без BOM.

Comment: За символы не слышал, но определенные строки можно. [Может чем то поможет вам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/453423/Чтение-определенных-строк-из-файла-txt)

Comment: Получается, что мне нужно Байты определенные заменить в файле

Comment: FileStream умеет читать и писать с определенных позиций не считывая целиком файл.

Comment: По аналогии [с этим](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208592/reading-parts-of-large-files-from-drive) делаете себе запись и чтение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте для этого Stream

```
var sybols = new char[] { '2', 'e', 'a', '+', 's' };
var index = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(new char[15]);
var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sybols);

using (Stream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    stream.Seek(index, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

Comment: думаю, что вопрос заключается несколько в другом. Каким образом ему вычислить позицию символа, вы уверены, что мы всегда должны смещаться на 15 позиций? А если в файле записаны китайские иероглифы?

Comment: Не подумал об этом сейчас поправлю

Comment: Нужно знать точную кодировку для таких операций

Comment: Кодировка в вопросе явно указана.

Comment: Добавил вычисление позиции

Comment: `GetByteCount(new char[15])` — а почему это верно? Вы ведь понимаете, что не зная реальных символов из файла, вы не можете, просто подставив нули, вычислить размер в байтах. UTF-8 — кодировка _переменного_ размера.

Comment: Хуже того, запись внутрь utf8-файла практически невозможна, ведь если ширина в байтах исходного текста не совпадает с шириной в байтах текста замены, вам придётся переписывать весь хвост файла.

Comment: Замена - равнозначна в моем случае

Comment: var index в моем случае и вправду не нужна, т.к. все символы будут весить только 1 байт.

Comment: @Mart: А почему тогда ваша кодировка utf8? Для utf8 символы вполне могут быть шире байта.

Comment: @VladD: У меня будут только цифры, переносы строк, и символ "-". utf8 - чтоб быстро можно было открыть через тот же notepad++ и посмотреть. И если без кириллицы работать - там на 1 символ будет 1 байт. Вроде удобно и без путаницы.

Comment: @Mart - Если вы уверены, что все символы умещаются в 1 байт, то не лучше ли взять кодировку ASCII?

Comment: @VladD: можно попробовать, правда мало понимаю в чем тут выиграю